# Create new record if its a new day, otherwise UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my application, I have 35 different websites, each has a site ID. On all of these websites there are different campaigns running on each site (Campaign_id)

My goal is to record how many hits a campaign had on a site each day. I need it to auto create the record if the site_id/campaign_id/todays date does not exists. If it does exist, it should only update the hits. In this example I just randomly generate a site id and campaign id for example sake

```
$site_id = rand(1,99);
$campaign_id = rand(1,99);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `out` (site_id,campaign_id,hits) VALUES(".$site_id.",".$campaign_id.",1)
          WHERE date = '".date('Y-m-d')."'
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits=hits+1, 
          date = '".date('Y-m-d')."'
          ");
```

The above will give me exactly what I want but the date field is always
0000-00-00. I need it to be todays date and the hits needs to be +1 on every transaction thereafter. Any of you people with awesomeness have an idea of how to alter this to get it working?

Comment: Some data might help to clarify the problem

Comment: The field `date` - is that set as an auto timestamp field - in the sql above you don't populate that field ( which should be encased with backticks in the sql btw ) - and... the `mysql` suite of functions are deprecated, switch to `mysqli` or `pdo`

Comment: What kind of data? site Site_ID is a random number and so is campaign_id. Hits is only hits+1 and the date is the current date.

Comment: If you use a random id for both `site_id` and `campaign_id` you can't hope to get consistent results surely

Comment: Yes, it will get updated to mysqli in the future but time constraints as of now are not letting me. The date field is set to the 'Date' type with no default or auto update. There is another field in the table that is called date_last_hit  and that is set to on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP however it is not useful to me and I will get rid of it.

Comment: Sorry RamRaider, in the example I have it set to random for example purposes however, I have 35 sites, each has a static site_id and run 1 of 99 campaigns but currently there are only 9 campaigns available

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. Just insert the date, effectively making each site, campaign and date unique. Once it is inserted, the next transaction will just update the hits. The following day, a new record will be created because the date has changed, and hits on the next day will be updated on the next days record.

```
@mysql_query("INSERT INTO `out` (site_id,campaign_id,hits,date) VALUES(".$site_id.",".$campaign_id.",1,'".date('Y-m-d')."')
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits=hits+1
          ");
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a unique index/constraint on `(site_id, campaign_id, date)`:

```
create index unq_out_site_campaign_date on `out`(site_id, campaign_id, date)
```

(Note that the columns can be in any order.)

Then you can insert into the table using code such as:

```
INSERT INTO `out` (site_id, campaign_id, date, hits) 
    VALUES(".$site_id.", ".$campaign_id.", CURDATE(), 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits = hits+1;
```

Presumably, your goal is to increment the hits for today.  If not, pass in the value for the current date and follow the same logic.